# Unity3d Set Player Icons By Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm trying to set My Player Icons by script,
but when I run the script it does nothing,
and I'm not getting any errors.
This is my code:

```c#
public void SetPlayerIcons()
{
    var iconSizes = PlayerSettings.GetIconSizesForTargetGroup(BuildTargetGroup.iOS);
    var icons = new Texture2D[iconSizes.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < iconSizes.Length; i++)
    {
        var iconPath = Path.Combine("Assets", BookIconsPath);
        var assetPath = iconPath+"/Icon_"+iconSizes[i]+".png";  
        Debug.Log("assetPath: "+assetPath);
        try 
        {
            icons[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Texture2D>(assetPath);
            if (icons[i] == null)
                Debug.LogError("Unable to load icon at "+ assetPath+" due to asset not found");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e) 
        {
            Debug.LogError("Unable to load icon at "+ assetPath+" due to asset not found");
            Debug.LogError("Exception:" + e);
        }
    }
    PlayerSettings.SetIconsForTargetGroup(BuildTargetGroup.iOS,icons);
}
```

Can someone help me with that?
What am I doing wrong?

Thank

Comment: Have you tried printing out the length of iconSizes?

Comment: yes,I'm getting the correct size.